# Tablesorter stickyHeaders not aligning with table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, tablesorter

My table header is not aligning with my table column.  On the left side of the table, I have a navigation sidebar that the table header somehow failed to recognize after scrolling past the original header (see pics below):
[image]

[image]

I tried wrapping the table in a parent div with the position set to relative, but the table header still doesn't behave correctly (see codes below):

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/theme.default.css' %}" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.tablesorter.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js' %}"></script>
<div id="tableWrap" style="position:relative;">
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <caption> ... </caption>
    <thead>
    <tr> ... </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr> ... </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').tablesorter({
        sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]],
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter', 'stickyHeaders'],
        widgetOptions: {
        //stickyHeaders_attachTo: '#tableWrap' 
        },
    });
});

</script>
```

Under widgetOptions, I tried "stickyHeaders_attachTo" pointing to the parent div but still cannot get the desired result.